# How do I increase the resolution of the Webots Pen device?

Tags: webots

I'm using the Pen device at the moment but I'm trying to get the resolution better finer so I can see smoother curves.

[image]

I'm currently just using the Webots Grass appearance. Is scaling the used texture or something like that the only way to improve the lines? The Webots documentation says "The precision of the painting action mainly depends on the subdivision field of the Geometry node. A high subdivision value increases the number of polygons used to represent the geometry and thus allows a more precise texture mapping, but it will also slow down the rendering of the scene.", but I'm using a plane with the Webots Grass texture and there is no subdivision option in the geometry of a Plane.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the actual resolution of the texture image used for the plane and the size of the plane. To improve the resolution of the pen drawings you have therefore two options:

1. Double the resolution of the grass image (using for example Gimp and scale-up the image to double the resolution, then save it). This should double the resolution of the pen drawings. You can do this as many times as needed to reach the desired resolution.
2. Reduce the `size` of the `Plane`. This should help as the texture won't be that much stretched up.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*